# 'nonetype' object is not callable, problema en mi interfaz grafica tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy

Hola buenas noches les venia a pedir ayuda con un problema en mi interfaz grafica, pasa que cuando yo ingreso una opcion y me tira el resultado, pongo regresar pero al presionar otra opcion no me tira la operacion ni entra a la ventana solo me sale "if num.get() == 0: 'nonetype' object is not callable", no se a que se referirá, gracias de antemano aqui esta el codigo entero.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import numpy as np
ventas = np.array([24,45,44,40,37,70,80,33,45,32,55,46,75,90,45,40,37,38,40,80,85,40,41,38,42,38,90,75,39,39,42,40,42,88,98,41,41,44,36,38,98,90,24,45,44,40,37,95,82,33,45,32,55,46,97,98,45,40,37,38,40,98,98,40,41,38,42,38,90,50,39,39,42,40,42,80,78,41,41,44,36,38,50,70]).reshape([4,3,7])
vendedores =["Juan Pérez", "María Acuña", "Pedro Fuentes"]
semanas=["Semana 1","Semana 2","Semana 3","Semana 4"]
dias = ["Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado","Domingo"]
ventas_d= np.zeros(3*7, dtype="i").reshape([7,3])
vendedores_max = []
M=1000
#----------------------------------- FUNCIÓN DE OPCIONES
def regresar(ventana_cerrar):
   ventana_cerrar.destroy()
   
def listado():
   return "\n   1.-Total vendido y promedio de ventas semanal      \n2.-Vendedores que alcanzaron la venta máxima   \n3.-Total de las ventas realizadas según selección  \n4.-Ventas totales del fin de semana seleccionado \n5.-Salir                                                                      \n"
#-------------------------------------- FUNCIONES VENTANAS

def ventana1():
   def Suma_Promedio ():
       ventas_s = []
       for j in range(len(semanas)):
           ventas_s.append(ventas[j].sum(axis = 1))
       prom_s = []
       for i in range(len(semanas)):
           prom_s.append(ventas[i].mean(axis = 1))
       for i in range(len(vendedores)):
           for j in range(len(semanas)):
               if nom.get()== vendedores[i] and sem.get() ==semanas[j]:
                   nombre= vendedores[i]
                   venta_sem=((ventas_s[j][i])*M)
                   semana=(semanas[j])
                   prom_sem=((prom_s[j][i])*M)
       resp_sp.set(" "+nombre+" la "+semana+" Vendió: $ "+str(venta_sem)+" y en promedio fue de $ "+str(round(prom_sem))+" ")  
   
   ventana1 = Toplevel()
   ventana1.title("Opción 1")
   ventana1.config(bg="Honeydew")
   ventana1.geometry("550x550")
   ventana1.resizable(0,0)
   ventana1.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
   nom= StringVar()
   sem= StringVar()
   totalSem= IntVar()
   promedio=IntVar()
   resp_sp= StringVar()
   casilla= Label(ventana1, text=" Seleccione vendedor ").place(x=180,y=100)
   nombre= Spinbox(ventana1, values=("Juan Pérez","María Acuña","Pedro Fuentes"), textvariable=nom).place(x=175, y=150)
   casilla2= Label(ventana1,text=" Seleccione semana ").place(x=190, y=200)
   semana= Spinbox(ventana1, values=("Semana 1","Semana 2","Semana 3","Semana 4"), textvariable=sem).place(x=175, y=250)
   boton= Button(ventana1, text="Confirmar", fg="green", command=Suma_Promedio).place(x=160, y=300)
   resultado= Label(ventana1, textvariable=resp_sp).place(x=30, y=400)
   botonRegreso= Button(ventana1, text=" Regresar ", fg="red",command=lambda: regresar(ventana1)).place(x=270, y=300)
   
def ventana2():
   def Venta_Max ():
       for i in range(len(dias)):
           for j in range(len(vendedores)):
               ventas_d[i,j]=(ventas[:,j,i].sum()) 
       vent_max =ventas_d.max(axis=1)
       for j in range(len(vendedores)):
           for i in range(len(dias)):
               if vent_max[i]==ventas_d[i][j]:
                   vendedores_max.append(vendedores[j])
               elif vent_max[i]==ventas_d[i][j]:
                   vendedores_max.append(vendedores[j])
               else:
                   vendedores_max.append(vendedores[j])
               
       for i in range(len(dias)):
           if d.get() == dias[i]:
               maximo=vendedores_max[i]
       dia=d.get()
       resp_max.set(" El Vendedor que alcanzó la venta máxima \n en el día "+dia+" fue de "+maximo)
           

   ventana2=Toplevel()
   ventana2.title("Opción 2")
   ventana2.config(bg="Honeydew")
   ventana2.geometry("550x550")
   ventana2.resizable(0,0)
   ventana2.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

   nom= StringVar()
   d=StringVar()
   resp_max= StringVar()

   casilla= Label(ventana2,text=" Seleccione semana ").place(x=190,y=100)
   dia= Spinbox(ventana2, values=("Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado","Domingo"), textvariable=d).place(x=170,y=150)
   boton= Button(ventana2, text="Confirmar", fg="green", command=Venta_Max).place(x=160, y=200)
   boton= Button(ventana2, text="  Regresar  ", fg="red",command= lambda: regresar(ventana2)).place(x=270, y=200)
   casilla2= Label(ventana2, textvariable=resp_max).place(x=120, y=280)

def ventana3():
   def Venta_rango ():
       sum_r=0
       advertencia=True
       venta_r = []
       dias_selec = []
       dia = [opc1.get(),opc2.get(),opc3.get(),opc4.get(),opc5.get(),opc6.get(),opc7.get()]
       for a in range(len(dias)):
           if dia[a]!=False:
               dias_selec.append(dias.index(dias[a]))
           else:
               advertencia=False
       for b in range(len(dias)):
           if dia[b]==True:
               advertencia=True
               
       while advertencia==False:
           messagebox.showwarning("Ventana de Advertencia","Error. Seleccionar alguna opcion")
           advertencia=True
           
       sem_selec = []
       for b in range(len(semanas)):
           if sem.get() ==semanas[b]:
               sem_selec.append(semanas.index(semanas[b])) 
       nom_selec = []  
       for a in range(len(vendedores)):
           if nom.get() ==vendedores[a]:
               nom_selec.append(vendedores.index(vendedores[a]))
               
       for a in range(len(dias_selec)):
           venta_r.append(ventas[sem_selec,nom_selec,dias_selec[a]])
       nombre =nom.get()
       semana = sem.get()
       for a in range(len(venta_r)):
           sum_r+=(venta_r[a])*M
       resp_ran.set("El monto total de las ventas realizadas por "+nombre+"\nen la "+semana+" fue de $ "+str(sum_r))
       

   ventana3=Toplevel()
   ventana3.title("Opción 3")
   ventana3.config(bg="Honeydew")
   ventana3.geometry("550x550")
   ventana3.resizable(0,0)
   etiqueta= Label(ventana3, text=" Seleccione el rango: ").place(x=190,y=50)
   opc1= BooleanVar()
   opc2= BooleanVar()
   opc3= BooleanVar()
   opc4= BooleanVar()
   opc5= BooleanVar()
   opc6= BooleanVar()
   opc7= BooleanVar()
   lun= Checkbutton(ventana3, text="  Lunes  ", variable=opc1).place(x=30,y=100)
   mar= Checkbutton(ventana3, text="  Martes  ", variable=opc2).place(x=160,y=100)
   mie= Checkbutton(ventana3, text=" Miércoles", variable=opc3).place(x=290,y=100)
   jue= Checkbutton(ventana3, text="  Jueves  ", variable=opc4).place(x=430,y=100)
   vier= Checkbutton(ventana3, text=" Viernes ", variable=opc5).place(x=90,y=150)
   sab= Checkbutton(ventana3, text="  Sábado  ", variable=opc6).place(x=220,y=150)
   dom= Checkbutton(ventana3, text="  Domingo  ", variable=opc7).place(x=350,y=150)
   nom= StringVar()
   sem= StringVar()
   resp_ran= StringVar()
   casillaSem= Label(ventana3, text=" Seleccione la semana: ").place(x=180,y=200)
   semana= Spinbox(ventana3,values=("Semana 1","Semana 2","Semana 3","Semana 4"), textvariable=sem).place(x=170,y=240)
   casillaVen= Label(ventana3,text=" Seleccione vendedor: ").place(x=180,y=280)
   nombres= Spinbox(ventana3,values=("Juan Pérez","María Acuña","Pedro Fuentes"), textvariable=nom).place(x=170,y=320)
   boton= Button(ventana3, text="Confirmar", command=Venta_rango).place(x=150,y=360)
   boton= Button(ventana3, text="  Regresar  ", command= lambda: regresar(ventana3)).place(x=270,y= 360)
   resultado= Label(ventana3, textvariable=resp_ran).place(x=50, y=450)
   ventana3.mainloop()


def ventana4():
   def Venta_finde (): 
       ventas_fs = []
       for x in range(len(semanas)):
           ventas_fs.append(ventas[x,:,5:7].sum())
       for y in range(len(semanas)):
           if sem.get() == semanas[y]:
               semana= semanas[y]
               total=((ventas_fs[y])*M)
       ventTotal.set(" La venta total del fin de "+semana+" fue de: $ "+str(total)+" ")

   ventana4=Toplevel()
   ventana4.title("Opción 4")
   ventana4.config(bg="Honeydew")
   ventana4.geometry("550x550")
   ventana4.resizable(0,0)

   sem= StringVar()
   ventTotal= StringVar()
   
   etiqueta= Label(ventana4, text=" Seleccione semana: ").place(x=210,y=100)
   semana= Spinbox(ventana4, values=("Semana 1","Semana 2","Semana 3","Semana 4"), textvariable=sem).place(x=190,y=150)
   boton= Button(ventana4, text="Confirmar", fg="green",command=Venta_finde).place(x=180, y=200)
   boton= Button(ventana4, text=" Regresar ", fg="red",command= lambda: regresar(ventana4)).place(x=290, y=200)
   resultado= Label(ventana4, textvariable=ventTotal).place(x=110,y=300)

#-------------------------------------- VENTANA PRINCIPAL

def Menu():
   def opciones():
       if num.get() == 0:
           messagebox.showwarning("Ventana de Advertencia","Error, Seleccionar una opción que este dentro de la lista dezplazada")
       elif num.get() == 1:
           num.get = ventana1()
           return num.set
       elif num.get() ==2:
           num.get = ventana2()
           return num.set
       elif num.get() == 3:
           num.get = ventana3()
           return num.set
       elif num.get() == 4:
           num.get = ventana4()
           return num.set
       else:
           num.get = ventana.destroy()
           return num.set
       return opciones
       
   ventana = Tk()
   ventana.title("La favorita")
   ventana.config(bg="Honeydew")
   ventana.geometry("1100x900")
   ventana.resizable(0,0)
   ventana.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

   calendario1= PhotoImage(file="calend.png")
   cal= Label(ventana, image= calendario1).place(x=550, y=40)
   calendario2= PhotoImage(file="calend2.png")
   cal2= Label(ventana, image= calendario2).place(x=550, y=320)
   calendario3= PhotoImage(file="calend3.png")
   cal3= Label(ventana, image= calendario3).place(x=550, y=600)
   nomTienda= Label(ventana, text=" La favorita ").place(x=210,y=100)
   menu= Label(ventana, text=listado()).place(x=100, y=250)
   num= IntVar()
   casilla= Label(ventana, text="  Ingrese su opción:  ").place(x=210, y=430)
   numeroCasilla= ttk.Combobox(ventana, values=(1,2,3,4,5), textvariable=num).place(x=190, y=490)
   Confirmar = Button(ventana, text="Confirmar", fg="green", command=opciones).place(x=240, y=560)
   ventana.mainloop()

Menu()
```

el error no se que a se referira, no se me ocurre nada ni veo algo raro, ese es mi error no me deja presionar una opcion nueva cuando presiono el boton regresar.

Comment: Buen día, adentro de opciones utilizas mal los `get` y `set`, ¿Qué debería hacer el programa al elegir una opción?

Comment: Yo creo que hace falta repasar como funciona en general `tkinter` pero las funciones relacionadas a tu problema son `get` y `set` ¿Qué intentas hacer en las líneas `num.get = ventana1()` y `return num.set`? No es la forma correcta de utilizarlas pero además no tienen sentido

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema está en la función `opciones`, lo único que necesitas es ejecutar las funciones de las ventanas y no veo la necesidad de retornar algo por lo que puedes quitar todos los `return` (A menos que necesites hacer algo que no has expuesto en la pregunta).

```
def opciones():
    if num.get() == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Ventana de Advertencia","Error, Seleccionar una opción que este dentro de la lista dezplazada")
    elif num.get() == 1:
        ventana1()
    elif num.get() ==2:
        ventana2()
    elif num.get() == 3:
        ventana3()
    elif num.get() == 4:
        ventana4()
    else:
        ventana.destroy()
```

Siempre es importante revisar la documentación antes de hacer algo. [Lectura recomendada.](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html)